# Jquery nth-child works only for first and last child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble with the nth-child selector, It works on THE first and THE last child, on the second one it goes wild and in the third it does not work at all (see jsfiddle):

https://jsfiddle.net/6r7261Lq/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="selezioni">
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="0"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="0">
<h2>0</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="1"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="1">
<h2>1</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="2"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="2">
<h2>2</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="10"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="10">
<h2>10</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="3"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="3">
<h2>3</h2></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selezioni a').on('click', function() {
c = $(this).data('costo');

    if (c === 0){
    $('#selezioni h2:first').css("color", "red");
    $('#selezioni h2:not(:first)').css("color", "black");
    }
    else if (c === 1){
        $('#selezioni h2:nth-child(2)').css("color", "red");
        $('#selezioni h2:not(:nth-child(2))').css("color", "black");
    }
    else if (c === 2){
        $('#selezioni h2:nth-child(3)').css("color", "red");
        $('#selezioni h2:not(:nth-child(3))').css("color", "black");
    }
    else if (c === 10){
        $('#selezioni h2:nth-child(4)').css("color", "red");
        $('#selezioni h2:not(:nth-child(4))').css("color", "black");
    }
    else if (c === 3){
        $('#selezioni h2:last').css("color", "red");
        $('#selezioni h2:not(:last)').css("color", "black");
  }
 });
 });
```

I'm getting mad with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:first-child`, `:last-child` and `:nth-child` all target where the element relative to it's parent. The `h3` is always going to only be the `:last-child` because it is the last child of it's parent. `:first` isn't the same as `:first-child`, either. `:first` will return the first instance of something. `:first-child` will target the first child in a parent.

If I understand the end goal, you want to target the `a` elements using `:nth-child`, then target the `h3` inside of that `a`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selezioni a').on('click', function() {
    c = $(this).data('costo');

    if (c === 0) {
      $('#selezioni a:first h2').css("color", "red");
      $('#selezioni a:not(:first) h2').css("color", "black");
    } else if (c === 1) {
      $('#selezioni a:nth-child(2) h2').css("color", "red");
      $('#selezioni a:not(:nth-child(2)) h2').css("color", "black");
    } else if (c === 2) {
      $('#selezioni a:nth-child(3) h2').css("color", "red");
      $('#selezioni a:not(:nth-child(3)) h2').css("color", "black");
    } else if (c === 10) {
      $('#selezioni a:nth-child(4) h2').css("color", "red");
      $('#selezioni a:not(:nth-child(4)) h2').css("color", "black");
    } else if (c === 3) {
      $('#selezioni a:last h2').css("color", "red");
      $('#selezioni a:not(:last) h2').css("color", "black");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#selezioni{
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
}
h2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: -23px;
 padding-left: 10px;

}
.costi {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selezioni">
 <a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="0"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="0">
 <h2>0</h2></a>
 <a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="1"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="1">
 <h2>1</h2></a>
 <a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="2"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="2">
 <h2>2</h2></a>
  <a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="10"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="10">
 <h2>10</h2></a>
 <a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="3"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="3">
 <h2>3</h2></a>
  </div>
```

And I'm not sure what the end goal is exactly, but the same functionality could be written a lot simpler. Toggle a class on the element you're clicking on and use CSS to change the colors https://jsfiddle.net/6r7261Lq/5/

Answer (score 0):

probably use nth-of-type(), becouse nth-child() count text nodes in html document like children

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Given a detailed question, you should either post a code or snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#selezioni a:nth-child(2) h2').css("color", "red");
$('#selezioni a:not(:nth-child(2)) h2').css("color", "black");
```

Edit:
[Michael Coker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1123505/michael-coker) suggests the same thing, and has a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would just reset them all before coloring the one that should be red.

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var $allH2 = $('#selezioni a h2');
  
  $('#selezioni a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $allH2.css('color', 'black');
    $(this).find('h2').css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selezioni">
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="0"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="0">
<h2>0</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="1"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="1">
<h2>1</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="2"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="2">
<h2>2</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="10"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="10">
<h2>10</h2></a>
<a href="#" class="costi" data-costo="3"><img src="immagini/crystal.png" alt="3">
<h2>3</h2></a>
```